# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $

Tags: kotlin, retrofit2, moshi

[Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d32UK.png)

[Json file looks like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0Aji.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co4ZZ.png)

[Trying to retrieve these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlKHr.png)

```
interface StationService {
    @GET("/bus/nearstation/latlon/[lat]/[lon]/[distance].json")
    suspend fun getStationData(): Response<List<Station>>
}
```

.

After Changes in Answer 1:

```
for (station in it) {
                stationNames.append(station.street_name)
                    .append("\n")
            }
```

Getting this error in MainFragment.kt:
For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on the structure of the response you need to have Class wrapping `List<Station>`: apply following changes:

```
    data class ResponseData(
         @SerializedName("data") val data: NearestStation
    )

    data class NearestStation(
         @SerializedName("nearststations") val nearestStations: List<Station>
    )
```

Where the station is the same data class that you have right now. Now change the retrofit service as following:

```
    interface StationService {
    @GET("/bus/nearstation/latlon/[lat]/[lon]/[distance].json")
         suspend fun getStationData(): Call<ResponseData>
    }
```

Why?
The root object in JSON object consist of two fields: `code` of type String (bypassed from example) and `data` which is object consist of one field called `neareststations` which is the list of stations. you need to follow the same object structure in you data class model.

---Edit:

You need to change following in your code:

If you made changes I mentioned to your retrofit service, you need change type of

```
val stationData = MutableLiveData<List<Station>>()
```

to

```
val stationData = MutableLiveData<ResponseData>()
```

and change

```
val serviceData = service.getStationData().body()
```

into

````
val serviceData = service.getStationData().execute().body()
```.

Pay attention that ```serviceData`` is from type  ```ResponseData``` not ```List```  So replace ```?: emptyList()``` with mocked ```ResponseData```
````

Comment: Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun <T> emptyList(): List<T>
Please specify it explicitly.

Comment: @WorkerThread
    suspend fun callWebService() {
        if (networkAvailable()) {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(WEB_SERVICE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .build()
            val service = retrofit.create(StationService::class.java)
            val serviceData = service.getStationData().body() ?: emptyList()
            stationData.postValue(serviceData)
        }
    }

Comment: I added some information to Edit section of response

Comment: I edited the code as you said and getting this new error: For-loop range must have an 'iterator()' method in mainFragment.kt

Comment: It says that ```it``` parameter is not from type of Iterable. In other words it's not array or list object. In this line: ```for (station in it)```.

Comment: Check it's type.

Comment: "it" is the value that was parsed in when my observer class received changes to the data

Comment: Check your mail. Thx

Comment: I checked the email, after applying all changes I recomended, change ```it``` to ```it.data.nearstStations```. My Answer is true if you follow all previous changes I asked to do